# JPA 2.1 - mapping entity using a column value

Tags: jpa, java-ee-7

Environment: EE7/JPA 2.1 (Glassfish 4/EclipseLink 2.5)

given the following database tables:

```
+-------------+
| Foo         |
+=============+
| id          |
| ...         |
+-------------+

+-------------+
| Bar         |
+=============+
| id          |
| ...         |
+-------------+

+-------------+
| Baz         |
+=============+
| id          |
| ...         |
+-------------+

+-------------+
| Parameter   |
+=============+
| id_generic  |
| type        |
| ...         |
+-------------+

'type' specifies the concrete table with 'id_generic' being the PrimaryKey of it.
```

What is the proper way, to map a structure like this in JPA/EclipseLink?

one possible solution may be using an artificial inheritance hierarchy like

```
@...
@Inheritance(strategy=SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type"...)
public abstract class Parameter {...}

@...
@DiscriminatorValue("FOO")
public class FooParameter {...}

@...
@DiscriminatorValue("BAR")
public class BarParameter {...}

@...
@DiscriminatorValue("BAZ")
public class BazParameter {...}
```

but this seems rather "ugly" to me, because the different subclasses do not differ in any way.

i know, there are other, implementation-specific solutions like using a constant value inside the @JoinColum like

```
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="Foo.ID" referencedColumnName="id_generic"),
    @JoinColumn(name="type" referencedColumnName="'FOO'") //FOO as constant value
});
private...
```

or the @Where Annotation in Hibernate. But what would be the solution in EclipseLink?

UPDATE:
DataModel Picture for clarification

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are after.  What is the entity model you want to use in the application?  Why is a foo/bar/baz subclass ugly for your needs?  If the Foo/Bar/Baz tables are exactly the same, why not put them in a single table?  Is this info read-only?

Comment: they are not the same, it's just Pseudo-Code. sorry, i thought this would be clear with the '...' substitution for other columns/properties.

Foo/Bar/Baz (again, not the real names ;-) ) are not the Problem. It is the Parameter table/entity, which is causing me some trouble. I want the Foo/Bar/Baz entities to contain a single Parameter Entity, which is determined through the combined id_generic/type column in the corresponding parameter-table.

Comment: Sounds like Foo extending parameter is what you want, as then all parameter data and logic is contained with in it. Single or joined table inheritance can set the type field for you.  If you have a problem setting this up, show the setup and the problem.  An alternative would be to have Foo reference parameter with a 1:1 but you have to set the type field in parameter when the reference is made.

Comment: thanks for your help, but thats not quite what i'm wanting, since Foo/Bar/Baz are unrelated. Maybe my 'workaround'-example using an artificial parameter inheritance got you confused.

what i am really looking for ,is sort of an standard compliant or at least EclipseLink variant of this:

http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.2/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_mapping_notes_nonstdjoins.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using a @VariableOneToOne mapping in EclipseLink,

http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_variableonetoone.htm

or using an Expression in your mapping's selection criteria,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/MappingSelectionCriteria